# Update content on iframe inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a language switch on a website which updates the displayed language in the main iframe. However, I am also using fancy box, which pops up out of the iframe, and is therefore an iframe within an iframe. I change the language to be displayed with the following code:

```
function setlang(lang) {
    var i;
    var len;
    var list;
    var ifr = document.getElementById('mainframe');
    var cw = (ifr.contentWindow || ifr.contentDocument);

list = cw.document.getElementsByClassName('langdiv');

    for (i=0, len=list.length ; i<len ; i++){
        list[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

list = cw.document.getElementsByClassName(lang);

for (i=0, len=list.length ; i<len ; i++){
    list[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
}
```

.....and here is the HTML:

```
<input id="EN" name="view" type="radio" onclick="setlang('EN'); sessionStorage.setItem('language', 'EN');">
<input id="DE" name="view" type="radio" onclick="setlang('DE'); sessionStorage.setItem('language', 'DE');">
<input id="FR" name="view" type="radio" onclick="setlang('FR'); sessionStorage.setItem('language', 'FR');">
```

Could someone please help me make this work whereby the iframe is not necessarily called 'mainframe' but is simply *any* iframe that has multiple languages? I suspect that this will necessitate converting most of my vars into arrays, something which I am not really confident about doing on my own. Thanks!

The website in question is: www.neuverband.ch

Comment: Nothing from anyone? If this post were a duplicate I would understand, but I haven't found anything on here which deals with this issue.